# Why is my function not terminating after return?

Tags: python, function, return, terminate, suffix

I'm creating a suffix tree using the string "BANANA$". When calling my findPath function from main as "print(findPath(root, "BANANA$", 5))", so checking if "A$" is a path from the root, I get the following output:

```
SEQUENCE: A$
  CUR CHILD: $
    NON-MATCH: $ 0
  CUR CHILD: A
    CHILD MATCHED: A
    NEW SEQ: $

SEQUENCE: $
  CUR CHILD: $
REACHED THE END!
  CUR CHILD: BANANA$
  CUR CHILD: NA
False
```

It prints out the line "REACHED THE END!", so clearly the function has touched that part of the code, bu why isn't my function terminating after the line "return True"?

```
def findPath(curNode, sequence, i):

    sequence = sequence[i:]
    print("\nSEQUENCE: " + sequence)

    for child in curNode.children:
        print("  CUR CHILD:", child.val)
        # print(len(child.val), child.val)

        # NO WAY IT CAN BE A MATCH, SO SKIP
        if (len(child.val) > len(sequence)):
            pass

        # POSSIBILITY TO MATCH
        else:
            curInd = 0
            count = 0

            # CHECK IF child.val MATCHES THE BEGINNING OF sequence
            while (curInd < len(child.val)):
                if (child.val[curInd] != sequence[curInd]):
                    print("    NON-MATCH:", child.val[curInd], curInd)
                    count += 1

                curInd += 1

            # child.val MATCHES THE BEGINNING OF sequence
            if (count == 0):
                # AN EXACT MATCH, SO REACHED THE END
                if (child.val == sequence):
                    print("REACHED THE END!")
                    return True

                else:
                    print("    CHILD MATCHED:", child.val)
                    newInd = len(child.val)
                    sequence = sequence[newInd:]
                    print("    NEW SEQ:", sequence)
                    findPath(child, sequence, 0)
    return False
```

Comment: The function is recursive. So after the recursive call returned, the caller continues.

Comment: Thanks. I added a global variable that's set to False initially, and instead of "return True" in my function I set the variable to True then return the variable instead of "return False"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After it returns from the recursive call, the parent function continues its `for loop`. If you want it to stop when the child has reached the end, you need to check the return value of the recursion.

```
                else:
                    print("    CHILD MATCHED:", child.val)
                    newInd = len(child.val)
                    sequence = sequence[newInd:]
                    print("    NEW SEQ:", sequence)
                    if findPath(child, sequence, 0):
                        return True
```

This will propagate the `True` value back up through the recursion stack.